# Combine data annotation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a collection of several attributes that should all be used always together for UI and Validation.  For example for a currency field, I have to add a UI Hint, Validation Logic, and Display Formatting.  As a result, my class looks very crowded.

```
public class Model
{
    [UIHint("Currency")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    [CustomRegularExpression(Currency.ValidationPattern, OnlyOnClientSide = true)]
    [SetMetaDataForCustomModelBinder("Currency")]
    public double? Cost { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Currency")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    [CustomRegularExpression(Currency.ValidationPattern, OnlyOnClientSide = true)]
    [SetMetaDataForCustomModelBinder("Currency")]
    public double? Profit { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to create a `[Currency]` attribute that combines the functionality of all these attributes to be one simple attribute? My goal would be to create the following:

```
public class Model
{
    [Currency] public double? Cost { get; set; }
    [Currency] public double? Profit { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I have tried creating a custom attribute, but there are no interfaces exposed that would allow me to implement the functionality of those different attributes.  I can subclass ValidationAttribute, but then I cannot also subclass UIHintAttribute.  Any other potential solutions I'm missing?

Comment: interesting question. This is @DarinDimitrov territory

Comment: My guess is you would need something like Postsharp and use AOP.

Comment: I'm curious on how this would be done. I would love to be able to do this

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720556/combine-asp-net-mvc-attributes-and-action-filters-annotations-together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822537/is-it-valid-to-replace-dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider-and-manipulate-the-r) and a reference from the post to Phil Haack's [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx) you can create your custom `AssociatedMetadataProvider` that adds attributes you need. You will have something like this:

```
public class MyCustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var attributeList = attributes.ToList();
        if (attributeList.OfType<CurrencyAttribute>().Any())
        {
            attributeList.Add(new UIHintAttribute("Currency"));
            attributeList.Add(new DisplayFormatAttribute
            {
                ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
                DataFormatString = "{0:C}"
            });
        }

        return base.CreateMetadata(attributeList, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
    }
}
```

And in application start event:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyCustomMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: @MattMurrell Did this solution work for you because it is not working for me--the UIHintAttribute is not working?